# "This URL contains an invalid domain"-error when registering Amazon Cognito domain with facebook app

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I am following https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/single-sign-on-sso-with-facebook-on-aws-cognito-angular-4a914ebfb1d8 to allow users to sign in to a userpool using Facebook. The cognito domain is https://myapp.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse, however, facebook app complains the  URL mostly the dash "-". But that is default behavior of cognito domain name. Anybody found a walk around?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turned out to be that the error sticks from an error previously introduced. After I "discard" and "add platform" again, everything is fine.